# Optimal temperature for Mpemba Effect

Tags: temperature, water, freezing

Is there an optimal temperature for the [Mpemba Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpemba_effect)? If so, what is it?

If a specific example is needed: There is a 100 milliliter sphere of water floating in air at -10 °C. At what initial temperature greater than ~10 °C<sup>1</sup> will the temperature of said water drop to 0 °C the fastest?

<sup><sup>1</sup>Or whatever the local maximum nearest to 0 °C in a temperature/time to freeze graph is.</sup>

Comment: [**There is no such thing as the Mpemba effect!**](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32989/) If you're talking about the *remaining* water freezing faster because you've evaporated most of the rest away, then this can't be answered without at the very least knowing the humidity of the air.

Comment: I don't think the evidence in the linked question is sufficient to conclude that there is no such thing as the Mpemba effect. Although John found that the layer of frost seemed to be responsible, I believe other people have done experiments that controlled for that, and under certain circumstances, they have still found the effect to work.

Answer (score 0):

To maximize Mpemba effect we have to maximize the entropy content of the drop.Supposed P=1 atm,to do this we have just to maximize the temperature.The maximum temperature we can get without loosing the drop by evaporation is 100 oC.

Comment: Find details in my article https://www.mdpi.com/660974