# How does the water anomaly affect the Mpemba effect?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water, ice, freezing

I understand basic explanation of [Mpemba effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpemba_effect) like this: Distant molecules are easier to realign into new formations.
But if we compared two bottles of water like in Mpemba effect and one of them had 4°C and the colder one 0°C would be outcome the same (4°C would freeze faster)?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32989/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122742/2451 and links therein.

Comment: This might answer your question:-
https://www.nature.com/articles/srep37665

Answer (score 1):

Yes,it is possible.The hotter water  could reach the temperature of the colder so to do ice formation begin while the colder water is appearing the supercooling effect.

Comment: Dear elias2010. For your information, Physics.SE has a [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/582/2451) that it is OK to cite oneself, but it should be stated clearly and explicitly in the answer itself, not in attached links.