# Will Ice Cubes Form Quicker when Made from Hot Water or Cold Water?

Tags: temperature, water, entropy, ice, cooling

When you put water in the freezer you can make Ice Cubes. But does the **time taken** for these Ice Cubes to form **decrease** or **increase** when the water which is used is **hotter** or **colder**?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32989/2451 and links therein.