# What's the thermal dynamics description of Mpemba effect?

Tags: thermodynamics, definition, non-equilibrium

Mpemba effect basically said that hot water cooled down to frozen faster than cold water.

A related post could be found here: 
[What is the status of Mpemba effect investigations?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32989/what-is-the-status-of-mpemba-effect-investigations)
(2012) but it's kind of out of date, and a numerous explanation could be found in [the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpemba_effect) page.

Another two papers, 
[one based on the kinetic theory and non Gaussian distribution](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.119.148001) (2017)
and 
[one based on the chemical potential in water molecular bound](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1310/1310.6514.pdf) (2014)
was presented in the recent years.

However, I was wondering, since it's a "statistical mechanics season" this time of the year, was there any way to describe such process in thermal dynamics language?(like $C_p$, $\Delta S$, etc.) 
How to analytically describe Mpemba effect?

(Of course, if anyone has any updated papers, feel free to post.)